# AJAX isEmail Check on Field Entry & Javascript Form Submit Disable/Enable

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, form-submit, email-validation, disabled-input

Using Twitter Bootstrap, have a form that lets the user submit a question to be answered publicly or privately.

To enable the "Answer Publicly" submit-button, the len text field should != 0.

To enable the "Answer Privately" submit-button (both graphically and functionally), the email field should run isEmail.php ([isemail.info/about](http://isemail.info/about)) via AJAX.

At the moment:

: clicking either submit buttons runs the question.php action, which oddly loads the question.php page (really just want this to send the form's email and question to a programmed email address).. Have yet to write the question.php, so assistance here too would be great..

: selecting the question text field removes the disabled class (graphical) from the Answer Publicly button, which doesn't account for str > 0 (need more javascript for this)..

: the Answer Privately button does not enable graphically, and functionally it has yet to disable in the first place..

Here is the HTML:

```
      <form class="form" id="contact_question" action="/question.php" method="post">
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="email" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" onkeyup="isEmailCheck(this.value)>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="text" id="inputQuestion" placeholder="Question" onKeyUp="document.getElementById('Apublic').className = 'btn';">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="control-group">
          <div class="controls">
            <input type="submit" class="btn disabled" id="Apublic" value="Answer Publicly">
            <input type="submit" class="btn disabled" id="Aprivate" value="Answer Privately">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Here is Submit Disable/Enable Javascript:

```
<!-- Disable/Enable Form Submit -->
<script>
$(function() {
  $(":text").keypress(check_submit).each(function() {
    check_submit();
  });
});

function check_submit() {
  if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
    $(":submit").attr("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $(":submit").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
}
</script>
```

Here is the isEmail AJAX:

```
<!-- AJAX isEmail -->
<script>
function isEmailCheck(str)
{
if (str.length==0)
  {
  document.getElementById("inputEmail").innerHTML="";
  document.getElementById("inputEmail").style.border="0px";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("inputEmail").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    document.getElementById('Aprivate').className = 'btn';
    document.getElementById("Aprivate").disabled = false;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("POST","/assets/isEmail.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```